# google api closest pair of points

Tags: google-maps-api-3, points

Is there a google api that will calculate closest pair of points?
Where I can give it many points, and it will calculate the shortest route between them?

thanks

Comment: I don't belite there is such API. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the Distance Matrix work for you?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix